# How to convert CSV file to Array?

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

For example, I have csv file and then imported to PowerShell:

```
$animal = Import-Csv “animal.csv”
$animal
```

Output is:

```
Animal
------
Bird
cat
dog
```

I would like to convert to array value, i.e. I would like to put these "bird","cat","dog" in array, basically like this:

```
$newanimals = "Bird","Cat","Dog"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newanimals = Import-Csv -Path "animal.csv" | Select -ExpandProperty Animal
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
Import-Csv ".\animal.csv" | Foreach-Object {$arrayOfAnimals += @($_.Animal)}
Write-Host $arrayOfAnimals #Bird cat dog
$arrayOfAnimals[1] #cat
```